# JavaScript not working in Google App Engine (PHP SDK)

Tags: javascript, php, google-app-engine

Javascript is not working in Google Apps Engine. Both in local machine and on appspot. Can't figure out where the problem is. Here is my code.

JS Script:

```
function runOnLoad() 
 {
document.getElementById('taskentry').value = "Enter your task here";
//document.getElementById('taskedit').style.visibility = "hidden";
//document.getElementById('edit').style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
```

app.yaml:

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /javascript
static_dir: javascript


handlers:
- url: /.*
script: task_list.php
```

HTML Code:

```
<body onload="runOnLoad()">

<form name="submittask" onsubmit="return validateTaskSubmission()" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="entertask" id="taskentry" onclick="runOnClick()" >

 <script src="/javascript/jsscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You really need to include what isn't working, what sort of errors you are getting, what you expect to happen and what debugging you have performed.

Comment: @TIm yes you are right. But I inluded the js script in the same file that of the php script and now everything is fine. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Can you access http://localhost:8080/javascript/jsscript.js (change 8080 based on your settings) on your local machine?

Comment: After a bit of tinkering I resolved it. The problem was I did some mistakes in the app.yaml file.